# formatting dates using apache poi when passing a string object

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, date-formatting

I need to format a date cell in excel to be dd/mm/yyyy

I appreciate this is maybe not the "correct" standard, but, this is what the client wants...

The date that I am passing in to the cell is formatted yyyy-mm-dd

So,

I have this code:

```java
Cell dateCell;
dateCell = row.createCell(3);
dateCell.setCellValue(p.getDateOfBirth());
CellStyle dateCellStyle = WorkBook.createCellStyle();
dateCellStyle.setDataFormat(creationHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd/mm/yyyy"));
dateCell.setCellStyle(dateCellStyle);
```

which according to this:
http://www.kscodes.com/java/writing-various-date-formats-in-excel-using-poi/ **(1)**

I believe should work. But when I create the excel file the date is still yyyy-mm-dd

I have looked here [How to set date field in excel using java apache poi library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319789/how-to-set-date-field-in-excel-using-java-apache-poi-library) and I notice that this uses the line

```java
cell.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);
```

but there is no mention of this in (1)

Anybody got any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14314913/14056755). Does this meet your needs?

Comment: Thanks marcin. I think it might but my code uses XSSFWorkbook and the code mentioned uses HSSFCell etc. Do you know if the two are compatible. I believe the difference is that one creates and excel.xls file and the other an excel.xlsx file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The date that I am passing in to the cell is formatted yyyy-mm-dd

This is the root cause of the problem. The API expects you to pass a `Date` object whereas you are passing a `String` object. You need to parse your date string into a `Date` object and pass the same to `dateCell.setCellValue` as shown below:

```
Cell dateCell;
dateCell = row.createCell(3);
Date dateOfBirth = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(p.getDateOfBirth() + "");
dateCell.setCellValue(dateOfBirth);
CellStyle dateCellStyle = WorkBook.createCellStyle();
dateCellStyle.setDataFormat(creationHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd/mm/yyyy"));
dateCell.setCellStyle(dateCellStyle);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Sir, That worked perfectly although I used LocalDate instead of simpleDateFormat. I'm sure I read somewhere that simpleDateFormat is soon to be deprecated. Either way, you helped me see the wood for the trees.